# Cannot access website from the same server

Tags: c#, email, smtp, exchange-server

I have a website on `http://SomeDomain.com`. when I go to that domain from any computer I am able to access the website. If I then go to that same domain but from the server that is hosting that website I will not be able to access the site. It looks like if a firewall will not be enabling the connection.

I know I can go to `http://localhost` from within that server in order to access the website.

Anyways **the problem is that I cannot send emails from that server** I have the following code to send an email:

```
public static void SendEmail(string toEmailAddress, string subject, string body)
{
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sales@domainName.com", "domainName");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(toEmailAddress);
        string fromPassword = "MY_PASSWORD";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "mail.toglcloud.com",

            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("v040\\sales.domainName", fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
}
```

when I run that code from any computer (I already tried 5 different ones) it works! But if I run that exact code on the server (computer hosting website and that contains mail server) it does not work. I get the following exception:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 206.155.112.15:587     at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)     at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
>   Exception& exception)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**I think it has to do with the same reason why I cannot find the endpoint `http://SomeDomain.com`**

Comment: Mayby is there anywhere in any config file ( i gues the config of the email program server ) an line that says to allow / block local adresses. Mayby if you change that it will fix...

Comment: Also, mayby [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181177/1846175) will help

Comment: I created a console application instead of the website and I get the same exception. Once I make it work on the console application I will put that code on the website.

Comment: Well, the point is that your computer / server can't find the SMTP host ( the same computer?!? ). So can you check if the SMTP server is listining on `port 587`?

Comment: I have already tried `SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis` when I tried died I got a different exception saying `System.Net.Main.SmtpExeption: Cannot get IIS pickup directory....`  Thanks for the help though I appreciate it :)

Comment: If your SMTP server is running at the right port, you can try to ping yourself ( mayby even traceroute if it helps )... Mayby that will give you ( and us ) some more information about what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

The difference between 5 other computers and the server:
1. Which user are you  logged in as? What are permissions for the user.
2. Firewall permissions (biggest chance since the mail server is totally not accessible)
3. For the website - is it IE permissions (often on the server this could be an issue)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've never seen a situation where the user account had anything at all to do with DNS resolution issues.  Also, considering it's the website itself that cannot contact the external mail server then the browser being used by the client has nothing at all to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I added an entry in the host file and it works well.

[image]

Comment: Remember, code—or, in this case, configuration data—should be referenced in markdown, not as a screenshot. Can you edit this answer to include the relevant part of your `hosts` file as a code block?